# Issue with work vs force for calculating spring constant

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, spring, calculus

Lets say I have a spring with spring constant k. I put a 10kg weight on the spring and it compresses the spring one meter before stopping. We know that at this point the downwards force is equal to the upwards force so we can calculate the spring constant to be $98$N/m by $kx = mg$.

However if we  use work to calculate the spring constant, we know that the work done by the block is equal to $Fd = 98J$, and the work done by the block is equal to the work done by the negative spring force. The amount of work done by the spring is the integral from 0 to 1 of kx. If we integrate this we get $(1/2)k = 98J$ and solving for $k$, we get $k = 196N/m$

It seems the first approach is correct, but where exactly is the second approach going wrong?

Comment: See the top answer linked question. When you release the block, and it starts falling down and extending the spring, the work done by gravity goes into (1) the PE of the spring and (2) the kinetic energy of the falling block. You need to take this KE into account.

Comment: aaah cool. Thank you very much